# ZK Framework getting displayed in source code

Tags: java, zk

The version of zk that we are using in our project is getting displayed by default in the HTML source code.
like this

**ZK 5.0.6 2011022418**

It seems like zk, when converting zul file to HTML add this comment by default.

I want to remove this comment getting generated in the HTML source code.

I tried to go through zkoss site but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because our zk version was old and zk core team didn't have any setting to disable it, we kind of found a way to stop zk version for getting displayed.

This is what we did
 - first, we found out from where the version of zk was getting put in response. we 
   found that 'org\zkoss\zk\ui\sys\HtmlPageRenders' is the class were it is done. 
 - Then we created the same package structure in one projected, remove the code for 
   version output, complied the code and replaced generated class files of 
   HTMLPageRenders in zk.jar.

And problem got solved !!!

I know this is not the right way and I have to do the same every time we upgrade our zk jars, but this is the only way we could do it.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following setting in **zk.xml**:

```
<library-property>
    <name>org.zkoss.zk.ui.versionInfo.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
</library-property>
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. It seems like because this property is available after '6.5.5' and we are using ' 5.0.6' version of zk, this property has no effect.Is there any other way using which I can hide the zk version ?

Comment: unfortunately no other ways for your version

Comment: We found a way to stop zk version getting displayed.What we did is first we found out from where version of zk was getting put in response. we found out that 'org\zkoss\zk\ui\sys\HtmlPageRenders' is the class were it is done. Then we created the same package structure in one projected, remove the code for version output, complied the code and replaced class files of HTMLPageRenders in zk.jar. And problem got solved !!!